# Object.ReferenceEquals does not behave as Expected

Tags: c#

I come across a misunderstood behavior in c# here is the full example Even Resharper Show me what I expect

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication11
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var str = EmptyArray<string>.Instance;
            var intTest = EmptyArray<int>.Instance;
            var intTest1 = EmptyArray<int>.Instance;  
            var str1 = EmptyArray<string>.Instance;
            int i=0;
            int j = 0;
            string s = "";             
            Console.WriteLine(str.GetType());
            Console.WriteLine(intTest.GetType());
            if (Object.ReferenceEquals(str,str1))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("References are equals");
            }
            if (Object.ReferenceEquals(intTest,intTest1)) ;            
            {
                Console.WriteLine("References are equals");
            }
            //this will be true so Why ? 
            if (Object.ReferenceEquals(intTest,str)) ;            
            {
                Console.WriteLine("References are equals");
            }
            //I know this will be always false 
            if (Object.ReferenceEquals(i,j))
            {

            }
            //this will be always false 
            if (object.ReferenceEquals(i,s))
            {

            }


        }
    }

    public static class EmptyArray<T>
    {
        public static readonly T[] Instance;

        static EmptyArray()
        {
            Instance =  new T[0];
        }
    }
}
```

this where the strange behavior to  me this will be true so Why ? Even Resharper give me a warning saying that "Expression is always false".

```
            //
            if (Object.ReferenceEquals(intTest,str)) ;            
            {
                Console.WriteLine("References are equals");
            }
```

Comment: Please explain what your code does and what you expect.

Comment: Resharper isn't a silverbullet

Comment: @CodeCaster I expect that  comparing an object reference between int and a string should be false

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer I completely agree

Comment: @Kobi because the returned  value is  true

Comment: @CodeCaster is the case  just debug the code that I given above

Comment: Why did you roll the edit back? Your code has way too much noise and has typos (`;` after `if()`).

Comment: For op, the typo made the result wrong..

Comment: ooops that's true  could you  please flag it as to be deleted

Comment: @CodeCaster that's different code. Your code compares nulls

Comment: @CodeCaster no, you've encountered a different issue: you're comparing null to null. See http://ideone.com/1w6x1o

Comment: @Paga yup, you're right. Nevermind that. I was thinking about an interesting case where all empty arrays point to the same object, but alas, it was just a typo. Creating an example as small as possible that reproduces the issue really helps towards writing a good question.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer actually  Resharper  was smart enough to catch the no-op and offer to remove the entire `if` statement.

Comment: please flag it as to be deleted

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos BTW I don't use Resharper. I use my mind. I just wanted to point out that I wouldn't use Resharper as argument to ask a question... I would check if Resharper is right about the concern before asking..

Comment: @BRAHIMKamel Don't remove the content of the post because you want a question deleted, that's not how things work here.

Comment: @bluefeet you have right but it was just  a typo issue could u delete it please

Answer (score 5, accepted):

that's becuase You are having semicolon at end of if statement

```
if (Object.ReferenceEquals(intTest,str)) ;   // remove this semicolon.
```

[Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/oVyFFD) is working dot net fiddle.

Answer (score 4):

That's because you have a typo:

```
 if (Object.ReferenceEquals(intTest,str)) ;
```

The check results in a no-op and the next block gets executed anyway

If you remove the semicolon the block will *not* be executed

```
if (Object.ReferenceEquals(intTest, str)) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("References are equals");
}
```